# C# ASP.NET MVC ENTITY FRAMEWORK Error 1 Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Error   1   Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 488, 553:EntityTypes Project_Dyn_Webapps.Models.Domain.Afwezigheid are being mapped to the same rows in table Afwezigheid. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.
C:\Users\Clauwaert\workspace\projectSVNCheckout\Project_Dyn_Webapps\Project_Dyn_Webapps\Models\Domain\WebSenseEtities.edmx  489 497 Project_Dyn_Webapps

anyone has had this error before and knows a fix for it?

ps: not sure what parts of code/design to post so just posted the error/problem

Comment: Retagged as entity framework, you'll get a different audience and possibly more answers that way.

Comment: How did you create your Entity Framework model? Have you manually added/changed anything in the mapping layer? Did you use database-first, model-first, code-only etc?

Comment: Glad you found it - do you want to edit back to your original question and post yourself an answer - that way other people with the same problem can retrace your workings :)

Comment: can you explain a little bit more, so other people will be able to figure out next time

Answer (score 0):

Found a [post](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/04/error-3032-problem-in-mapping-fragments-mapped-to-the-same-rows-in-table/) here, it may be helpful. It looks like you are trying to map hierarchy classes to the same table, and you need create some discriminate condition to map hierarchy class to the same table.

Comment: there is no inheritance involved.
http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6622/afwa.png